# Sum partial string (key word) matches in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a list of key words (around 300)

```
Key Word
abduct
attack
airstrike
bomb
```

And I want to iterate through an entire DataFrame's (df1) column (Text) in order to find  ANY instance in which the key word(s) appear. My ultimate goal is to have total counts for each key word.

```
Text                                Location     Date 
Police have just discovered a bomb. New York    4/30/2015, 23:54:27  
...
```

I know I can use str.contains (see below) to find the totals for each word on an individual basis, but I'm looking for an easy way to calculate the totals all at once.

```
word_count = df1[df1['Text'].str.contains('Key Word').count()
```

I have also tried to solve my problem with a script that splits all of the data in 'Text' into individual key words and sums the total, but this fails to take into account any key words that have spaces (at least in its current form).

```
 In [31]: df.Text.str.lower().apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x.split(" "))).sum(axis =0)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to split all the text into a list of individual words and then scan the list just once, using a dict to count the number of occurences. You could start by doing

```
word_list = (df1.Text + ' ').sum().split()
```

This will give a single list of all words in the column. The addition of the space to each prevents concatenation of consecutive entries. Then scan the list an count the keywords:

```
word_count = dict((keyword, 0) for keyword in keywords)
for word in wordlist:
     try:
         word_count += 1
     except KeyError:
         pass
```

`dict` look up is O(1) and you just have to scan wordlist once so it's algorithmically sound. The only problem that I can think of now is key words with multiple words. However, you could simply treat the words that make up a key word (phrase) as key words and count them. Then infer the the frequency of the key phrase. This isn't perfect but if there is no overlap between the words that make up key phrases it will work and could still work depending on the overlaps. I imagine it would suffice but I can't know without seeing all the keywords.

EDIT: I thought of a way to do the same thing using just `pandas`:

```
word_series = pd.Series((df1.Text + ' ').sum().split())
word_series.value_counts().loc[key_words]
```

This will give you the number of occurances of each single key word. It still doesn't solve the key phrase problem.

However, here's a solution that works for two-word key phrases:

```
two_word_series = word_series + ' ' word_series.shift(-1)
# a series of all consecutive pairs in the word_series
two_word_series.value_counts().loc[two_word_key_phrases]
```

This can be generalised to n-word phrases but get's cumbersome after awhile. It's feasibility depends on the max length of your key phrases.

Comment: Thanks, Joe! That definitely solves my big problem, but the keyword list contains quite a bit of phrases with considerable overlap between the words that make up the phrases. Any thoughts about a work around?

Comment: Hard to say. Suppose we reduced all phrases to no more than two words and treated each word as a key word. I imagine you could probably infer from the counts, as they have to come in singles or pairs. For example if one was 'bombs away' and another 'away in a manger' then two 'away' + one 'bomb' + one 'manger' must be one of each. But even this is a lot of work compared with just scanning the original column 300 times. A compromise is to use my solution in so far as it's possible and then use your original on the phrases that won't yield to it.

Comment: Also, if a keyword is in another key phrase, is it counted once or twice? It seems the key words should be 'more' unique than they sound.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution which can include specific phrases (which you know before hand) in your count, you could replace the spaces in the the phrases with another character (say "_"). For example:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame(['Police have discovered an air bomb', 'Air strike the bomb', 'The air strike police are going on strike', 'Air bomb is full of hot air'], columns = ['text'])
keywords = ['bomb', 'police', 'air strike']
keyword_dict = {w:w.replace(' ', '_') for w in keywords}

corpus = ' '.join(df.text).lower()
for w,w2 in keyword_dict.items():
   corpus = corpus.replace(w,w2)

all_counts = Counter(corpus.split())
final_counts = {w:all_counts[w2] for w,w2 in keyword_dict.items()}
print(final_counts)
{'police': 1, 'air strike': 1, 'bomb': 2}
```

A more general solution (possibly better practice from a text-mining point of view where you won't necessarily know beforehand what phrases you're looking for), you could extract all bigrams from the text and perform a count over the whole thing:

```
corpus = ' '.join(df.text).lower()
words = corpus.split()
bigrams = [' '.join([words[i],words[i+1]]) for i in range(len(words) -1)]
print(Counter(words + bigrams))
Counter({'air': 5, 'bomb': 3, 'strike': 3, 'air strike': 2, 'police': 2, 'air bomb': 2, 'the': 2, 'discovered': 1, 'bomb is': 1, 'the bomb': 1, 'have discovered': 1, 'full': 1, 'bomb the': 1, 'going on': 1, 'are going': 1, 'are': 1, 'discovered an': 1, 'the air': 1, 'hot air': 1, 'is full': 1, 'hot': 1, 'on strike': 1, 'is': 1, 'strike the': 1, 'police have': 1, 'bomb air': 1, 'of': 1, 'strike police': 1, 'of hot': 1, 'an': 1, 'strike air': 1, 'on': 1, 'full of': 1, 'police are': 1, 'have': 1, 'going': 1, 'an air': 1})
```

Comment: Doesn't this involves scanning a string (corpus) which is the sum of the text column as many times as there are keywords? If so, it doesn't seem any better than the OP's original solution which just to scan the column for each key word (phrase), and probably slower since it's not vectorized. It's also way more convoluted.

Comment: The more general solution worked perfectly, thank you!